# Listing data with join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join, right-join

I have the following question related to joining tables together in SQL:

List all `products` that have not been sold on `13.05.2003`. Taking into account the tables `Orders`, `LineItem` and `Product`.
[image]

What I have coded is the following:

```
SELECT p.Pid, p.Label
 from Product p natural join line_item l
natural join Orders
where Date <> "2003-05-13"
```

The problem is that when I execute this code it appears more data tan it should be and I am not sure how to get rid of duplicates with `join`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safer to use `NOT EXISTS`. For example:

```
select *
from product p
where not exists (
  select null 
  from lineitem i
  join orders o on o.oid = l.oid and l.pid = p.pid
  where date <> "2003-05-13"
)
```

Or you can use `NOT IN`:

```
select *
from product 
where pid not in (
  select l.pid
  from lineitem i
  join orders o on o.oid = l.oid
  where date <> "2003-05-13"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I tried  the follwoing and it worked:

```
select product.pid, product.label
from ((product  inner join line_item on product.pid = line_item.pid) inner join orders on orders.oid = line_item.oid)
where not orders.date ='2003-05-13'
group by product.pid;
```

Thanks a lot for your answers, they helped me to find the right path to solve it